# Bevel tool issue (Not a scale reset issue)

Tags: bevel

I have been having this issue for some time and seems to be pretty persistent although to greater and smaller degrees. When beveling, it seems the some edgeloops follow the expected curve, but the rest seem to create a linear shape. Im honestly not sure how to describe this better but please see the attached GIF. As mentioned, this is not a scaling issue. I have reset all of this. It is incredibly frustrating and I have not seen anything about it in my searches

[image: Bevel Issue]

Comment: The middle face is an ngon which will have unpredictable behavior

Comment: Maybe share a representative  file on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the difference you are talking about?

[image]

'Loop Slide' is often necessary when bevelling over existing bevels

Comment: Unfortunately Loop slide does not resolve this specific issue.

Also, although it is an N-gon, and I agree this can cause issues, this happens on properly edge looped edges as well unfortunately..